# how to align two shortcode element side by side horizontally

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code . I want the two elements at the bottom "php echo do_shortcodewcas-search-form, php do_action(hamzahshop_custom_min_cart)" to be aligned horizontally on the same line, I am very new to this and have no idea how to do this , I have raked this entire platform but still no solution.

```
        <?php
/**
 * Displays Header
 *
 */

?>
<div class="header-main hamzahshop-custom-header">
<div class="container">
<div class="header-content">
        <div class="row" >
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
            <div class="logo"> 
            <?php
            if ( function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' ) && has_custom_logo() ) {
                      the_custom_logo();
            }else{
            ?>

                <?php if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) : ?>
                    <h1><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home" class="site-title"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <p class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
                if ( $description || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
                     <p class="site-description"><?php echo esc_attr($description); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>



             <?php }?>   


             </div>



          </div>



         <div>


     <?php echo do_shortcode('[wcas-search-form]'); ?>


     <?php do_action('hamzahshop_custom_min_cart');?>

          </div>
        </div>



        </div>



</div>    
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: First, try to remove your php. It's a distraction for now. Then make a runnable example to makes it easier for us to analyse this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap both content in ***span*** which is inline in nature. That means both end up coming side to side horizontally.
But in case you have the php content with tags that have block nature, you can go with ***display:flex*** property.

```
<style>
 .flexBox{ 
    display : flex; 
    justify-content : flex-start; //ensures content flows from left to right
 }
</style>

<div class = "clearfix flexBox" >
 <span><?php echo do_shortcode('[wcas-search-form]'); ?></span>
 <span><?php do_action('hamzahshop_custom_min_cart');?></span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Daniel cherac thats great,  if it worked will you accept the answer, people can focus on it